# failure of nested lambda functions generated in imported module

Tags: python, lambda, nested

I'm trying to develop a module which will be automatically convert my parameters in to python objects and create a dictionary with parameters and objects. More over the module has to substitute parameter value if it find a parameter name given by @name@.

Here the code and an example at the end.

```
#FILE convertor.py
import types 

is_lambda = lambda value    : isinstance(value, types.LambdaType) and value.__name__ == '<lambda>'

def builder(tree, target, item, delimiter):
    if delimiter not in item:
        return item
    result = ''
    copir = item.split(delimiter)
    for prefix,var in map(None,copir[::2],copir[1::2]):
        if prefix is not None: result += prefix
        if var is None: continue
        lmdcheck = is_lambda(tree[var])
        if lmdcheck or delimiter is '@':
            result += target+"[\""+var+"\"]"
        elif delimiter is '$':
            result +=  str(tree[var])
        else:
            return None
    return result

def resolve_name(tree, target, item):
    """
    Resolves links and string in RHS of parameters
    """
    # Resolve links First
    result = ''
    bld = builder(tree, target, item ,  '@')
    if bld is None: return None
    result = bld
    # And then Resolve strings
    bld = builder(tree, target, result, '$')
    if bld is None: return None
    result = bld
    return unicode(result)

def generate(params, target, parent=None):
    """
    @function generate generate recods in root initial directory
    @param params      - list of (name, value) records
    @param target      - string of variable name which will be generate (need for lambda(s)), 
    @param parent      - methodtree object which will be updated
    """
    if parent is None:
        try:
            exec target+"= {}"
        except BaseException as e:
            self.error("Cannot create target object self.{}: {}".format(target,e),"generate")
            return None
    else:
        try:
            exec target+"= parent"
        except BaseException as e:
            self.error("Cannot create target object self.{}=parent: {}".format(target,e),"generate")
            return None
    try:
        exec "tree = "+target
    except BaseException as e:
        error("Cannot create temporal variable tree for return target object:".format(e),"generate")


    for name, value in params:
        value = resolve_name(tree, target,value)    
        try:
            exec "{}[\'{}\']={}".format(target,name,value)
        except BaseException as e:
            error("Cannot execute operation self.{}[\'{}\']={}: {}".format(target,name,value,e),"generate")
            return None
    return tree

if __name__ == "__main__":
    params=[
        ['parameter', '3'],
        ['Varibale X','5'],
        ['Pwered X','@Varibale X@**@parameter@'],
        ['FunctionA','lambda x,p:x**p'],
        ['FunctionB', 'lambda k:@FunctionA@(k,$parameter$)']
    ]
    dic = generate(params,'dic')
    for n in dic:
        print n, dic[n], type(dic[n])
        if n == 'FunctionA':
            print "FunctionA:", dic[n](2,3)
        if n == 'FunctionB':
            print "FunctionB:", dic[n](2)
```

So everything work perfectly if I run python convertor.py

```
$ python convertor.py 
FunctionA <function <lambda> at 0x7ff116246848> <type 'function'>
FunctionA: 8
Varibale X 5 <type 'int'>
FunctionB <function <lambda> at 0x7ff1162468c0> <type 'function'>
FunctionB: 8
parameter 3 <type 'int'>
Pwered X 125 <type 'int'>
```

However when I import generate from my convertor.py, nested lambda functions don't work.

```
#File test.py
from convertor import generate
params=[
    ['FunctionA','lambda x,p:x**p'],
    ['parameter', '3'],
    ['FunctionB', 'lambda k:@FunctionA@(k,$parameter$)']
]
dic = generate(params,'dic')
for n in dic:
    print n, dic[n], type(dic[n])
    if n == 'FunctionA':
        print "FunctionA:", dic[n](2,3)
    if n == 'FunctionB':
        print "FunctionB:", dic[n](2)


FunctionA <function <lambda> at 0x7fe037994848> <type 'function'>
FunctionA: 8
FunctionB <function <lambda> at 0x7fe0379948c0> <type 'function'>
FunctionB:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 14, in <module>
    print "FunctionB:", dic[n](2)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'dic' is not defined
```

I couldn't find any similar topic in SO, but it may be a duplicate.

I probably understand why this happens. I just wondering is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's global variables are not truly global: they are on a per-module basis.  Furthermore, functions remember the module in which they were defined, and lookup any global references there, rather than in the module from which they are called.

So, your generated lambdas are being `exec`ed in convertor.py's namespace, and will attempt to look up `dic` there.  A possible solution would be to add a parameter to `generate()`, specifying the context you want to use for global names: your code generation statements would look like `exec <something> in context`.  You would normally pass `globals()` for this parameter, to use the calling module's globals.

Comment: So it will be `generate( .... context=globals() )` and in generate it will `exec .. in context`. Is it correct?

Comment: Should be something like that.  I haven't actually tried your code, and honestly don't understand it well enough to be sure this isn't going to lead to some other problem.